# Регулярные выражения IMG

Tags: php

```
Есть куча img с разными описаниями(alt) и с частичным различием в путе до файла:

<img alt="USA" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/b/22/Us.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="En" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/2/2f/En.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="Pr" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/c/g1/Pr.png" width="18" height="12">
```

Необходимо с помощью регулярки заменить путь до файла, во всех img что бы он стал таким:

```
<img alt="USA" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/Us.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="En" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/En.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="Pr" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/Pr.png" width="18" height="12">
```

Comment: Каким таким? Что за путь? Где путь?

Comment: @nick_n_a поправил вопрос, автор не оформил код подобающе

Comment: Как то не понятна задача. Не логично через **regex** пропускать весть код php, может проще отредактировать сам первоначальный код? В пути правку проще сделать через implode и explode

Comment: Приведите фрагмент кода где вы собираетесь править ваши img, что бы было понятно насколько сложный нужен фильтр.

Comment: Дело в том что этот текст с другого сайта, поэтому необходима динамическая замена при поступлении, Если данное решение не логично, подскажите тогда, какое может быть адекватное решение поставленной задачи.

Comment: так может не переживать и делать замену `src="(http://ftorofl.ru/images/)([^"]+)/([^"]+)"` на `src="\1\3"`.

Comment: '$content = preg_replace('src="(http://ftorofl.ru/images/)([^"]+)/([^"]+)', 'src="\1\3"', $content);' Выдает ошибку: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: вон ниже написали. Нужно просто слеши экранировать и для замены правильные символы использовать. Я просто в документацию пхп не смотрел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для HTML нужно использовать парсер:

```
require 'HTMLParser.php';

$html = str_get_html(<<<DATA
<img alt="USA" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/b/22/Us.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="En" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/2/2f/En.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="Pr" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/c/g1/Pr.png" width="18" height="12">
DATA
);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
  $element->src = preg_replace("@\/images\/.+?([^\/]+?\")@", "/images/$1", $element->src);
```

Но можно и просто регуляркой:

```
$str = <<<DATA
<img alt="USA" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/b/22/Us.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="En" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/2/2f/En.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="Pr" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/c/g1/Pr.png" width="18" height="12">
DATA;

$new = preg_replace("@\/images\/.+?([^\/]+?\")@", "/images/$1", $str);
var_dump($new);
```

https://repl.it/DFBw

Comment: Спасибо, большое '$content = preg_replace("@\/images\/.+?([^\/]+?\")@", "/images/$1", $content);' все как нужно. Очень благодарен.

Comment: @user218856, пожалуйста. Примите ответ, если он Вас устроил.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$str = '<img alt="USA" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/b/22/Us.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="En" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/2/2f/En.png" width="18" height="12">
<img alt="Pr" src="http://ftorofl.ru/images/c/g1/Pr.png" width="18" height="12">';

$pattern = '/(<img[^>]+)src=["\']([^"\']+)\/([^\/"\']+)["\']/';
$str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) {
  return $match[1].'"http://ftorofl.ru/images/'.$match[3].'"';
}, $str);

echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

Comment: Есть подозрение что Вы слегка перемудрили :)